# Is it possible to pass the record type of a lightning page into the lwc that's being referenced on that page?

Tags: lightning-web-components

So I have a Case lightning record page. Then I created a LWC to display some text depending on the record type of the page and put that LWC into the lightning record page. The text that is displayed is controlled by a property in the LWC. I can only pass in a constant string into the property from the lightning record page. I don't know how to pass in a variable (record type). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You can pass the record Id to LWC and then query the recordtype using getRecord adapter. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294471/how-to-pass-the-record-id-to-controller-method-from-lwc

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass it in directly. What you're expected to do is to call LDS (Lightning Data Service). You do this by importing the method and then using the magic api attribute recordId:

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import RECORDTYPEFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/ObjectName/RecordTypeId';

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [RECORDTYPEFIELD] })
  record({data,error}) {
    console.log(getFieldValue(data,RECORDTYPEFIELD));
  }
}
```