# LWC Unable to Pass recordId to Apex Method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass the recordId and Flow API Name from my LWC to an Apex Class using the imperative method.
I have not issue passing the Flow Name however I recordId is always returning as Null.

I compared my code to that in the post below, but could not find the issue
[How to pass the record id to controller method from LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294471/how-to-pass-the-record-id-to-controller-method-from-lwc)

**LWC js**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import callFlow from '@salesforce/apex/FlowController.callFlow';

export default class LaunchFlowDemo extends LightningElement{ 
  flowname = 'CaseFollow_Unfollow';
  @api recordId;
  @api async invoke() {
    let result = await callFlow({flow_name: this.flowname},{flow_recordId: this.recordId});
  }
}
```

**Apex Class**

```
public class FlowController {
     
   public FlowController(){
    }
      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)
      public static void callFlow(Id flow_recordId, String flow_name) {
      
       system.debug('flow_recordId =' + flow_recordId);
       
      //string flowName ='CaseFollow_Unfollow';
      //Id recordId='5004V00001AOwDAQA1';
      
      Map<String, Object> recordMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        recordMap.put('recordId', flow_recordId);
        
      Flow.Interview myFlow = Flow.Interview.createInterview(flow_Name, recordMap);
      
      myFlow.start();
    } 
}
```

Comment: in what type of page is your lwc used?

Comment: pls check that in your `invoke` method, just before you call the apex, is the `recordId` filled

Comment: @gills - I am calling this from an Action button on the record page - there is no LWC page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue - it was not with the recordId rather they syntax i was using for the Apex Method.  I was putting each of the parameters in separate braces.  I adjusted the code accordingly...

**LWC js**

```
import callFlow from '@salesforce/apex/FlowController.callFlow';
import {LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class LaunchFlowDemo extends LightningElement{ 
    
    flowname = 'CaseFollow_Unfollow';
    
    @api recordId
    @api async invoke() {
      
      callFlow({flow_recordId: this.recordId, flow_name: this.flowname})  
          .then(()=>{
              this.showToast("Success",'Case Unfollowed',"success")             
          }).catch(error=>{
              //error handling
              this.showToast("Error",error.message,"error")
          });
      }
    showToast(title, message, variant){
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title, message, variant
        }))
    }
}
```